# Embed Visual Studio editor into my app

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is it possible to embed Visual Studio 2010 (Express ?) source code editor into my application.

What is another most preferred way to interconnect my application with Visual Studio?

Don't want to embed my app into visual studio for some religious reasons =)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make your application a plug-in then make a plug-in that provides an interface for your application using some sort of IPC.

Also see [Embed Visual Studio 2010 Editor into a Tool Window](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/07/28/LearnVSXNow_2D00_Part45.aspx). As far as I understand, application has to be a plug-in/extension in order to do that.

Comment: yes, thnx, not a solution, but interesting idea.
but it is not suitable for Express edition :|

Answer (score 0):

MSDN How to: Get References to the DTE and DTE2 Objects
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw.aspx
is interesting starting point for solving my problem.